# AJAX Request - get HTTP Code/Response Header for successful request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the HTTP Response Code/Response Header from my AJAX request. Here's my original script:

```js
$("#callContact1").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.server.com?type=makecall",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
      console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError);
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
})
```

which is working fine. I've updated this to try and get the HTTP response code/header and view this in the console.log but I'm not seeing anything there. Here's my updated script:

```js
$("#callContact1").click(function() {
  console.log('starting call back request');
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.server.com?type=makecall",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
      var httpStatus = (data.status);
      var httpResponseCode = (data.getAllResponseHeaders);
      console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
      console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
      console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError);
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
})
```

but I'm not getting anything in the console (the request is executed successfully though). I also noticed the output from the 2nd line of the updated script is also not appearing in the console either.

Comment: clear your browser history and then try

Comment: anything in the console about CORS perhaps? or Access-Control-* headers?

Comment: I restarted by browser and I'm now seeing the entries in the console, but I'm getting "undefined" values instead of the expected values:

httpStatus: undefined
httpResponseCode: undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the above code to

```
.then(function(data,status,xhr) {
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
      var httpStatus = status;
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.status);
      console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
      console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in jQuery's documentation for jQuery.ajax()

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax#jqXHR

you can use .done() and .fail() or using [.then()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) which incorporates both, using two callback functions as parameters, the first for success and the second for fail.

So, you could use smt like this:

```
.then(function(data, status, xhr) {
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
    var httpStatus = status;
    var httpResponseCode = (xhr.status);
    console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
    console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
}, function(data, status, xhr) {
    var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + status;
    console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError); //make alert visible 
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError).show();

})
```